# What is the meaning of U.Ve. in letters or invitations?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I've read (or actually seen) a lot of places where a person's name (or an acharyas name) starts with the initials U.Ve.?

I have researched but unable to figure out the meaning of U.Ve.?

Can someone tell me what is the abbreviation of U.Ve?

1. What is stands for?
2. Why many of them use it?

Comment: Can you give examples to clarify it more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `U Ve` is short for `Ubhaya Vedantacharya` meaning one who is well versed in both the Sanskrit Vedanta (Upanishads, etc) and the Tamil Vedanta (Tiruvaymozhi, etc).
2. It is used as a standard prefix just like `Sri`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, is U.Ve. a tamil word?

Comment: It is a Tamil abbreviation. yes.